# unable to modify MVC 4 bult-in login controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the mvc4 application built-in account registration and login controllers(and their respective models). I've my own method for deleting accounts. So I want to put a check in the standard login controller, so that it checks if I've deleted the account myself and then redirect the person to an informative page.

However, when the controller gets called it just passes my line of code and still logs the user in. I've checked the DB. The user has 0  set to its IsActive(that lists accounts as "active" and "inactive") value and should get redirected. But he just logs in like my line of code doesn't exist...

This is the code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
 if (WorkerDAL.IsActive(model.UserName)) RedirectToAction("DisplayDeletedUserMessage", "Home");    //my redirect code

 if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
         {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
         }

     // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
 ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
 return View(model);
}
```

The code from my DAL class:

```
public static bool IsActive(string _username)
{  TimeTrackerEntities db = new TimeTrackerEntities();
   foreach (Worker worker in db.Workers)
   {
       if (worker.UserName == _username)
       {
             if (worker.IsActive == 1) return true;
             if (worker.IsActive == 0) return false;
       }
   }
return true;
}
```

Am I using the wrong action to user for my redirect? Or something obvious like that? I'm basically lost...

edit - Thanks to Eric J. and Jonathon Page the code is now working. Thank you both! 
How can I note both of their comments as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the return keyword:

`RedirectToAction("DisplayDeletedUserMessage", "Home");    //my redirect code`

Should read:

`return RedirectToAction("DisplayDeletedUserMessage", "Home");    //my redirect code`

Comment: You are also correct! I made two stupid mistakes... Also, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I assume this line:

```
if (WorkerDAL.IsActive(model.UserName)) RedirectToAction("DisplayDeletedUserMessage", "Home");
```

should read

```
if (!WorkerDAL.IsActive(model.UserName)) RedirectToAction("DisplayDeletedUserMessage", "Home");
```

It looks like you're currently redirecting to display the deleted user message if the user *is* active.

Comment: You are correct. I made a stupid mistake...
Thank you for taking the time to go over my code!